# Any languages with serializable / mobile runtime?

Tags: java, mobile, distributed, cloud-computing

I am developing a system that executes arbitrary jobs. A job is a piece of code in some programming language (e.g. Javascript), it can run sub-jobs and wait for their completion as it is shown in the following snippet:

```
class Job {
    async run() {
        let subResult = await run_subjob();
    } 
}
```

I want to be able to start program, stop the execution at `await`, save the runtime state, save it in some persistent storage, efficiently wait for the subjob's completion, load runtime back, continue execution. The OS-related resources (db connections, files and such stuff) referenced in the program can be guarded by using wrappers that maintain an execution session id and reinitialize entities when it doesn't match the global session id.

Are there any programming languages that support this feature (AFAIK it is called Code Mobility)?

P.S. I found out that something similar was popular in 90s and was called "Mobile Agents" but I can't find any maintained libraries.